# Google Custom Search searchbox not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, search

I've just created a Google Custom Search for my website. There are 2 parts of code: for searchbox and for search results. I inserted the first code into the body tag, but searchbox doesn't appear on the website.

What I'm doing wrong?!

```
  <body>
<div>
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '004556147665872853919:poyz6b7kmfw';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully used the Google Custom Search Engine V2 code on my WordPress site for almost 3 years. After upgrading to WordPress 4.4 the  search box element wouldn't display. Inspecting the page with Firebug revealed the search box code was there but no amount of CSS tweaking would make it visible.

I tried the DEMO LINK2 with Updated URL code and it almost worked, but only if I used gcse:searchbox instead of 'searchbox-only'. The search box displayed but the search results were rendered within the search box widget instead of on a 2nd page having the gcse:searchresults-only code like before. This is the expected behavior of gcse:searchbox as it displays both the box and results in the same page.

After hours of troubleshooting I reverted back to the GCSE V1 code. Problem fixed! I can't explain why.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the corrected way in the demo link below.

Check your HTML once more, I have kept HTML and Script separate.Although This doesn't matter but just cross check once.

```
<gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox>
```

[DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/GPLyM/3/)

[DEMO LINK2 with Updated URL](http://jsfiddle.net/GPLyM/5/)

Demo link 1 with javascript embedded into html:

```
<body>
<script>
 (function() {
    var cx = '004556147665872853919:poyz6b7kmfw';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox>
```

Comment: Also, I am not sure how you have generated the URL you can use the following CX instead of yours..   var cx = '017643444788069204610:4gvhea_mvga';